# Get error while cask, brew-cask

Tags: elasticsearch, homebrew

I want install search engine `elasticsearch` in OS X 10.11.6

I read [some blog](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/wv82/solution-for-elasticsearch-java-is-required-to-install-this-formula-in-mac-os)

in my command line

```
brew install elasticsearch
```

and it show error(needs java)

```
elasticsearch: Java 1.7+ is required to install this formula.
You can install with Homebrew Cask:
  brew install Caskroom/cask/java

You can download from:
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

I flow this blog's solution

```
brew tap caskroom/cask
```

and show

```
Warning: Tap caskroom/cask already tapped.
```

second command

```
brew install brew-cask
```

it show error

```
Error: No available formula with the name "brew-cask"
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
This formula was found in a tap:
Caskroom/cask/brew-cask-completion
To install it, run:
  brew install Caskroom/cask/brew-cask-completion
==> You haven't updated Homebrew in a while.
A formula for brew-cask might have been added recently.
Run `brew update` to get the latest Homebrew updates!
```

and i install java

```
brew cask install java
```

but cask doesn't install

```
==> brew cask install Caskroom/cask/brew-cask-completion
Error: Unknown command: cask
```

and Some blog give me some advice

```
brew upgrade brew-cask
```

it show error

```
Error: No available formula with the name "brew-cask"
```

if fact I can't understand why my mac can't find cask...

please somebody helpme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved I need to brew update

```
brew update
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this works for me.

I thought it's brew update install package command,

> brew install --cask java